# Haskell - choose l n function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have to write a function `choose l n` that prints a list of all possible combinations to choose `n` elements of a list `l`.

As an example the call `choose [1,2,3] 2` returns `[[1,2], [1,3], [2,3]]` or `[[2,1], [3,1], [3,2]]`

Unfortunately I do not understand the solution:

```
choose :: [a] -> Int -> [[a]]
choose _ 0 = [[]]
choose [] _ = []
choose (x:xs) n = (map (\ys -> x:ys) (choose xs (n-1))) ++ (choose xs n)
```

I understand the first two statements. The last line is not clear to me.

Can someone explain it, please?

Comment: Which part is confusing?

Comment: Can you evaluate the last line by hand, or start by evaluating parts of it with the hrlp of ghci

Comment: One fun thing about this implementation is that it is productive on infinite lists, with sensible results, if you think about it in the right way. 
`choose [1..] 3` == `[[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,2,5],[1,2,6],[1,2,7],..]`

Comment: Pascal's Triangle!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can choose `n` elements from `x:xs` in two ways: either `x` is chosen, or it is not.

If `x` is chosen, we are left with choosing `n-1` elements from `xs`. So, we recursively do `choose xs (n-1)` and then we add `x` on top with `map (\ys -> x:ys)`.

If `x` is not chosen, we are left with choosing all the `n` elements form the tail `xs`. So, we consider `choose xs n`.

Finally, we put together all such choices with `++`.

Answer (score 4):

The function prints all possible combinations given a list and number of elements for a combination. What the last line does is to apply this recursively given a non-empty list and a positive integer.

First, let's look at this part:

```
(map (\ys -> x:ys) (choose xs (n-1)))
```

This uses the very first element as a kind of 'constant'. It first generates combinations of the other elements recursively, and then puts the 'constant' element at the head of each list generated as a result

e.g. If input is [1,2,3] and 2 element combinations are needed, the function will be evaluated as follows:

```
 choose [1,2,3] 2
= choose (1:[2,3]) 2
= (map (\ys -> 1:ys) (choose [2,3] 1)) ++ (choose [2,3] 2)

choose (2:[3]) 1
= (map (\ys -> 2:ys) (choose [3] 0)) ++ (choose [3] 1)

= [[2]] ++ [[3]]
= [[2],[3]]
```

Because

```
choose 3:[] 1
= (map (\ys -> 3:ys) (choose [] 0)) ++ (choose [] 1)
= [[3]]
```

So,

```
 choose (2:[3]) 1
= (map (\ys -> 2:ys) ([[]])) ++ ([[3]])
= [[2],[3]]
```

And therefore,

```
 choose (1:[2,3]) 2
= (map (\ys -> 1:ys) ([[2],[3]])) ++ (choose [2,3] 2)
= [[1,2],[1,3]] ++ (choose [2,3] 2)
```

The second part in the above expression is nothing but `++ (choose xs n)` from the original definition. All it does is to repeat the above process with a smaller sublist of the original list.

Continuing the example above, `choose [2,3] 2` evaluates to [[2,3]]

Putting it all together, you end up with [[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]], which is the output you get.